# Sharing code between WPF & DNX Webapp

Tags: c#, wpf, web-applications, share, dnx

I have a WPF application under the .Net framework 4.5 and a web app under the DNX Core.
I want to share some code between those two apps.

I tried to create a "portable classe library" ... with no result.
I tried to do it with a nuget package ... with no result (and too complex to dispatch modifications)

Thanks for your propositions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally when creating a portable class Library, you can be compatible with .NET 4.5 and Dnx project. The only problem is that .Net 4.5 relies on csproj when your Dnx project relies on project.json.

Thus you won't have it out of the box, check out your options here: [What are my options for sharing code between DNX / ASP.NET 5 projects (project.json / xproj) and other C# projects (csproj) within a single solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355208/what-are-my-options-for-sharing-code-between-dnx-asp-net-5-projects-project-j)

Note that this solution will probably not work in the next version of [dotnet core](https://dotnet.github.io/) if they finally remove the project.json...